# rails 4 update_attribute with unobtrusive javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following link which is generated in loop

```
<% if category.status %>
    <%= link_to 'Disable', edit_category_path(category), method: :get, remote: true, confirm: 'Are you sure you want to disable' %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Enable', edit_category_path(category), method: :get, remote: true, confirm: 'Are you sure you want to enable' %>
<% end %>
```

In my edit action I have

```
unless params[:id].blank?
      @category = @category.update_attribute(:status, false) # Here I mentioned false as static.
end
```

If I click enable it should enable(update as true in database) and if I click disable it should disable(update as false in database)

How can I do it. How do I pass the status(true or false for updation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
<%= link_to 'Disable', edit_category_path(category, {status: 0}), method: :get, remote: true, confirm: 'Are you sure you want to disable' %>
```

And you can call as

`params[:status]` in controller

Answer (score 0):

If 'GET edit_category_path' is the usual 'produce a form which POSTs to #update,' the GET shouldn't update server state.

Maybe POST (probably directly to #update), to change status, then GET the edit_... path
Or POST to a new action that updates status and redirect to #edit?